# Creating Dynamic buttons and acessing some specific buttons

Tags: c#

I was doing one project in that i have doubt of linking Combobox values with Dynamically created buttons? and in those buttons, if 'n' number of buttons are created the how can i aceess only some specific buttons.. what should i do to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like

```
public void enableAsRequired()
{
    if (comboBox.Text.equals("something"))
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        ...
    }
    else if (...) { ... }
    else {...}
}
```

and call it from the events [TextUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.textupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SelectedItemChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the textbox